# Error popping up when trying to test xcode ios app on device "object file format unrecognized"

Tags: ios, xcode, device, ipod

Hello I'm having a problem when I try to test my App on my iPhone Touch!

Here is what the error says:

```
**CodeSign /Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.app cd /Users/scerip/Desktop/haqu-tweejump-9a05d35 setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate /usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: Jens Gleerup (4JA43UQ24Y)" --resource-rules=/Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/tweejump.build/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.build/tweejump.xcent /Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.app

/Users/scerip/Desktop/Projects/Debug-iphoneos/tweejump.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1**
```

What to do?

Comment: Is this happening while executing an Xcode scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you dont have your Provisioning Profile right installed...

Comment: Well, have you got a paid Apple Developer Account?

Comment: Go to the Apple Member Center
Go to IOS Provisioning Portal, then go to Certificates and add your Developer certificate as described.
If you did this go to "Devices" and add a Device, like your iPhone.
then go to App ID's, and follow the steps to create one unique App ID, this ID, your Certificate and the Device are needed to create a Provisioning Certificate under "Provisioning Profiles".
When you followed all the steps, go to Xcode, Press CMD+SHIFT+2 to bring up Organizer, go to "Devices" (your iPhone has to be plugged in) then go to Provisioning Profiles @ your device

Comment: Edit because no characters Left:
On the Section Provisioning Profiles on your Device click on "New" in the lower left corner to bring up the Login screen for requesting profiles.
Then enter the information if required and Xcode should do the rest.
If questions remain dont fear to ask.

Maurice A.

Comment: Hey, no problem, thats what i am here for :)!